# not able to delete the row from two table in mysql

Tags: mysql

my query is

```
delete ip.*,im.* 
from INPUT_MAPPING im  
left outer join INPUT_CONFIGURATION ip on(im.INPUT_ID=ip.INPUT_ID)
where ip.INPUT_ID=78
```

here INPUT_CONFIGURATION is a parent table and INPUT_MAPPING is a child table and
INPUT_ID is a primary key for INPUT_CONFIGURATION table and foreign key for INPUT_MAPPING table

using this query i am not able to delete a row from INPUT_MAPPING table as well as from INPUT_CONFIGURATION table which has common INPUT_
as 78

error coming as after executing is

> 11:19:52  delete ip.*,im.* from INPUT_MAPPING im  left outer join
> INPUT_CONFIGURATION ip on(im.INPUT_ID=ip.INPUT_ID) where
> ip.INPUT_ID=78
>
> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row:
> a foreign key constraint fails (clover_converter.INPUT_MAPPING,
> CONSTRAINT INPUT_MAPPING_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (INPUT_ID) REFERENCES
> INPUT_CONFIGURATION (INPUT_ID))   0.0033 sec

Comment: Why do you use a left join in your delete statement? Do you really want to delete an entry in your parent table? That's the error you get. You probably have another entry in Input_Mapping which matches the primary key you delete.

Comment: i want to delete the entry from the both parent table(INPUT_CONFIGURATION) as well as from child table(INPUT_MAPPING).i found this query in many sites and its not working. is there any other alternate solution to delete entry from both the table completely..?thanks

Comment: How do you define your foreign-key- constraint? What are the actions for `ON DELETE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like the Parent and Child terms and you feel they are easy to be remembered, you may like the translation of `ON DELETE CASCADE` to Leave No Orphans!

Which means that when a Parent row is deleted (killed), no orphan row should stay alive in the Child table. All children of the parent row are killed (deleted), too. If any of these children has grandchildren (in another table through another foreign key) and there is `ON DELETE CASCADE` defined, these should be killed, too (and all descendants, as long as there is a cascade effect defined.)

The FOREIGN KEY constraint itself could also be described as Allow No Orphans! (in the first place). No Child should ever be allowed (written) in the child table if it hasn't a Parent (a row in the parent table).

For consistency, the `ON DELETE RESTRICT` can be translated to the (less aggresive) You Can't Kill Parents! Only childless rows can be killed (deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think it is safe to assume you have CASCADING DELETES turned on.
All that is needed in that case is

```
 DELETE FROM MainTable
 WHERE PrimaryKey = ???
```